# Firefox's title bar tuns white upon opening a window

Tags: windows, firefox, themes, title-bar

In the first boot and in any subsequent window open, the title bar on my Firefox turns white, even though I use a dark theme:

[image: Firefox with dark theme but bright title bar]

Note that the shade of white is not the default theme's, but a fullbright white.

This started happening once I used Winaero Tweaker to change the default Windows title bar color to dark gray.

I understand that WT might cause issues, but is there a solution to this? It would be very interesting to having the best of both situations, dark Firefox and dark default.

Comment: I would ask the developers of the tweaker software.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try reversing your steps, and seeing if you can figure out the root cause. Tweaker may be conflicting with the Firefox theme and breaking it. If there is a way to disable the tweaker then reload Firefox and see if the theme displays properly, that may be an indicator that the tool is breaking the particular theme. Have you tried other dark themes in Firefox?